# Starting out with psql shell for PostgreSQL in windows

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm trying to learn about databases from the book *seven databases in seven weeks* and I don't understand the environment **psql shell**...

In the book they simply say following (I assume they mean to use the shell)

> create a schema called book using the command

```
$ createdb book
```

but the shell just asks for server, username, port, database and only allows connecting to the already created database *postgres* that is a maintanence database, whatever that means... The shell doesn't respond at all to the *createdb*-command.

this is what it looks like
[image]

What have I misunderstood and how do I create a database and use it in psql shell? It sucks to have bought a book in the beginning of a course not being able to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createdb` is an operating system utility. Run it in Windows command shell (cmd), like any other commands in this book starting with dollar sign.

Alternatively you can issue `create database book;` command in psql -- it's the same thing.

Comment: `create database book;` worked! psql shell didn't respond since I didn't have a semicolon after the command.